# Symfony2: Entity created but, give class does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

i had created an Entity class db_logs

```
namespace Acme\SuperBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class db_logs

{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11,  columnDefinition="INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", columnDefinition="TEXT  NOT NULL")
 */
protected $log;
}
```

The Doctrine entiry create all database tables perfectly

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme\SuperBundle\Entity
```

now i try to use in DefaultController with this code:

```
namespace Acme\SuperBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        /*
         * Test connect db
         */
        $mysql_fetcher = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('AcmeSuperBundle:db_logs')    
                    ->findAll();
        $output=array("latest"=>$mysql_fetcher);   
        return $this->render('AcmeSuperBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $output);
    }  
}
```

But when i go to web/app_dev.php

i receive this message error. what's going wrong?

```
Class 'Acme\SuperBundle\Entity\db_logs' does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - MappingException
```

I'm sure that entity file exist. Why Symfony2 doesnt found the entity file?

Answer (score 0):

you have to include it in your `DefaultController`

```
use Acme\SuperBundle\Entity\db_logs;
```

Also, have you created the `db_logs` Repository?

Then, add this few useful annotation to the `db_logs` Entity.

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="db_logs")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\SuperBundle\Repository\db_logsRepository")
 */
class db_logs {

  // ...
}
```

Comment: No, where i've to put the db_logs Repository? into Entity directory?
I'm tring to read manual and some howto, but nothing found about.
Too poor examples or explanations for me :(

Comment: yes exactly. Where you create the new Entity with the console it's asking to create also the Repository. Symfony will put the Repository into Entity folder, then you have to move it into Repository folder.

Comment: so i've to re-do console operation?

Comment: i also watching this esample(http://egeloen.fr/2013/12/01/symfony2-doctrine2-entity-listener-as-serice/) that uses listener class, but i never understand where put the files. or create it

Comment: i put listeners in `EventListener` folder, but it doesn't matter where you put it. You just have to set in the `config.yml` where to find it.
And to create it, just create a new PHP class since it's self-contained and it doesn't extends anything.